# How to fix mismatched brackets in a TeX string?

Tags: regex, perl, text-processing

For example I have a lot of Tex strings like

```
|u(x,t)|^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(4+t)^2))e^{-\frac{2(x-k_0t)^2}{1+4t^2))
```

The problem with the above Tex is that the bracket is not matching. `\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(4+t)^2))` should be `\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(4+t)^2}}` and `{-\frac{2(x-k_0t)^2}{1+4t^2))` should be `{-\frac{2(x-k_0t)^2}{1+4t^2}}`

```
wrong: \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(4+t)^2))
right: \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(4+t)^2}}

wrong: {-\frac{2(x-k_0t)^2}{1+4t^2))
right: {-\frac{2(x-k_0t)^2}{1+4t^2}}
```

**explanation:  The first example is not right, because for last two `)` there is no `)` matching it, and it should be `}` to match previous `{`**

I want to know how to automatically correct such mismatched brackets? I have perl installed and I intended to do it with regex, but can't figure out a way.

Comment: Where are those coming from? Are they part of a larger file? Are they always on individual lines, or part of a large block of text that can contain line breaks in the middle?

Comment: Just as a corner case: What happens, when single parentheses/braces are part of the formulae, e. g. as literals in a document about Regular Expressions?

Comment: @simbabque Hi, simbabque. The string in my post is a single complete Tex form of a math formula

Comment: For those of us that are not famiilar with TeX, this explanation is meaningless. Please [edit] and include a couple of full lines from the file.

Comment: This is impossible in general unless there is a clear pattern to the errors. That is why programming languages issue an error like *missing semicolon* instead of just fixing it for you. Where did this data come from, and how were the mistakes made in the first place?

Comment: @Borodin This string is copied from wikiwand page. Wikiwand is an addon for browser to reformat wikipedia page http://www.wikiwand.com/ . However, they mess up the Tex information behind equation image. I contacted the developer, but they don't give me feedback. So I tried to postprocess copied string myself. But I just found there are not only mismatched brackets, sometimes there are excess bracket. Maybe you are right, without knowing the exact pattern, this may not be done

Comment: @user15964: Hmm If I knew the syntax of TeX then I would have a stab at it, but it sounds a lot of work starting from what I already know. You should try an angry tweet: there's nothing like public criticism to get things fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly, but it sounds to me like you need to count brackets and make sure that the number of `( or [ or {` is equal to the number of corresponding `) or ] or }`.

One possible solution is using a hash for every line of TeX and storing values in it (not sure how the file looks. I assume all lines are like you provided):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift;
my $line_num = 0;
open FH, "<$file" or die "Error: $!\n";
while(<FH>) {
    my %brackets = (
        '('     =>      0,
        '['     =>      0,
        '{'     =>      0
    );
    $line_num++;
    my @chars = split //, $_;
    ### Count brackets.
    foreach my $char (@chars) {
        if ($char eq '(' or $char eq '[' or $char eq '{') {
            $brackets{$char}++;
        } elsif ($char eq ')' or $char eq ']' or $char eq '}') {
            if ($char eq ')') { $brackets{'('}--; }
            if ($char eq ']') { $brackets{'['}--; }
            if ($char eq '}') { $brackets{'{'}--; }
        } else {
            next;
        }
    }
    ### Check that all hash values are 0.
    foreach my $bracket (keys %brackets) {
        if ($brackets{$bracket} != 0) {
            print "In line $line_num: '$bracket'    missing $brackets{$bracket} closing brackets.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This code will at least tell you where the errors occured and give you a general idea of the nature of these errors. for input such as `)ff){gfs[[y[46rw]` the output will be:

```
In line 1: '{'  missing 1 closing brackets.
In line 1: '['  missing 2 closing brackets.
In line 1: '('  missing -2 closing brackets.
```

Instead of printing the brackets (or storing the number of brackets. Probably better to store index of the brackets) you can write simple code to fix this because at this point, you'll have all the information you need.

This is not a simple question if the errors in the file have no pattern. I recommend looking for one before actually trying

Comment: Thank you yonyon 100 for providing this useful script

Comment: You're welcome @user15964. Another idea that comes to mind (if TeX works that way) is to iterate over the lines and for every opening bracket, push it to a stack. When encountering a closing bracket, check the top of the stack and see if it resembles the closing bracket. If so, pop it from the stack. If not, replace the closing bracket with the appropriate bracket (still the one at top of the stack) and pop it. That should give you at least a well written bracket style.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some kind of condition, which indicates where the parenthesis are used instead of the braces. I assume that it is either in front of `e^` and at the end of the line.

This fixes the first one:

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/\)\)e\^/}}e^/' file.tex
```

And this the second:

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/\)\)$/}}/' file.tex
```

Comment: Hi, ceving. Thank you very much for answering. But the matching of bracket is not according to `e^` or end of line. Sorry for my unclear post. The `)` is not right, because there is no '(' matching it, and it should be '}' to match previous '{'

Comment: If you do not want to write a full TeX parser, you have to find some heuristics.